# I can't get this reaction time tester to output the information to a csv file

Tags: python, csv

```
import time


print("><><><><><><><><><><><><><")
print("> Reaction Time Tester <")
print("><><><><><><><><><><><><><")
name = input ("Please enter your first name: ")

time.sleep(1)
start=time.time()
text = input("Press enter on keyboard")
end = time.time()
duration = round(end-start,2)
print("Reaction Time: " + str(duration)+ "seconds.")
```

#Saving the results to a csv file

```
csv = (name + "," + duration + "/n")
win = open ("ClickTestResults.csv","a")
win.write(csv)
win.close()

time.sleep(60)
```

This is the error it shows when I run it:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\theun\Desktop\click test.py", line 20, in 
> csv = (name + "," + duration + "/n")
> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str

Comment: Use string formatting: `csv = f'{name},{duration}\n'`

Comment: `duration` is of type `float` so you have to cast it as `string`, do it like this: `(name + "," + str(duration) + "/n")`. You can concatenate string with float with the `+` sign.

Answer (score 0):

```
csv = (name + "," + str(duration) + "/n")
```

or better

```
csv = f'{name},{duration}\n'
```

Edit: context added per comment advise from Carlo Zanocco

In the first example I kept the original format of the code, but the duration value is not a string and can not be concatenated with the other strings, so it is wrapped in the str function.

The second example is considered "better" because the formatting is easier to read and the duration is automatically converted to a string in the process.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.